# linspace for arbitrary length 1D array

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

In numpy, one can do

```
>>> np.linspace([1,2,3], [4,5,6], 4)
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [2., 3., 4.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

However, it seems this isn't available from rust ndarray's [`linspace`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.linspace) which only accepts `Float`.

How do I generalize rust-ndarray's `linspace` to accept 1D arrays (`Array1<T>`) of arbitrary size?

Answer (score 0):

May not be optimized, but one way is the following

```
fn linspace<A:Float>(start: Array1<A>, end: Array1<A>, n: usize) -> Array<A, Dim<[usize; 2]>>{
  assert!(start.len() == end.len());
  Array::from_shape_vec((start.len(), n), (0..start.len()).map(|idx| Array::linspace(start[idx], end[idx], n)).flatten().collect()).unwrap().reversed_axes()
}
```

Basically,

1. `assert!(start.len() == end.len());` asserts same length
2. `(start.len(), n), (0..start.len()).map(|idx| Array::linspace(start[idx], end[idx], n))` repeatedly calls `Array::linspace` on each index which results in a nested `Vec<Array<...>>`
3. `.flatten().collect()` flattens the `Vec<Array<...>>` into a 1D `Vec<...>`
4. `Array::from_shape_vec().unwrap()` converts the `Vec<...>` into a `(start.len(), n)` sized `Array` (this is required since flatten arranges the elements as such)
5. `.reversed_axes()` transposes the array into shape `(n, start.len())` as is the case in numpy's linspace

This passes the following test

```
mod tests {
  use ndarray::array;

  use super::*;

  #[test]
  fn test_linspace() {
    assert_eq!(linspace(array![1.,2.,3.], array![4.,5.,6.], 4), array![[1.,2.,3.],[2., 3., 4.], [3.,4.,5.], [4.,5.,6.]])
  }

}
```